# Web scraping, Url jump prevents authorization?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape this website (www.dearedu.com), specifically, i've been having tremendous amounts of difficulties logging in...having tried everything I could find on previously answered authorization questions on stack exchange.

Currently, I am using request sessions to log in using the following code,

```
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

    mySession = requests.session()
    mySession.headers.update({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'})


    data = mySession.get('http://www.dearedu.com/', cookies = cj)


    data= {'userid': myusername, 'pwd': mypassword,
    'fmdo': 'login', 'dopost': 'login',
    'keeptime': '604800', 'teshu': 't'}

    data = mySession.post('http://club.dearedu.com/member/index_do.php', data=data)
```

when the code above is run with the correct password and username, you get the following html

```
<head>
<title>第二教育网提示信息</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
<base target='_self'/>
<style>div{line-height:160%;}</style></head>
<body leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
<center>
<script>
      var pgo=0;
      function JumpUrl(){
        if(pgo==0){ location='http://www.dearedu.com'; pgo=1; }
      }
document.write("<br /><div style='width:450px;padding:0px;border:1px 
solid #DADADA;'><div style='padding:6px;font-size:12px;border-
bottom:1px solid #DADADA;background:#DBEEBD 
url(/plus/img/wbg.gif)';'><b>第二教育网提示信息！</b></div>");
document.write("<div style='height:130px;font-
size:10pt;background:#ffffff'><br />");
document.write("成功登录，现在转向系统主页...");
document.write("<br /><a href='http://www.dearedu.com'>如果你的浏览器没
反应，请点击这里...</a><br/></div>");
setTimeout('JumpUrl()',1000);</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing I do not understand is that  the cookies and status code received indicate that I have successfully logged in, but when I try to then access the main page it indicates that I am not.

If i had to take a guess is that it has something to do with the url jumping. Specifically the website waits for like a second or so before redirecting you to the main page.

Can someone explain what is wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

EDIT:

"成功登录，现在转向系统主页" = successfully logged in, redirecting to homepage
"如果你的浏览器没反应，请点击这里" = If your browser does not respond, please click here

The rest I do not think is relevant. Thanks!